# how to set cost of subscription plan in transaction window in php

Tags: php

I am making website using php, html, javascript. I have three subscription plans when clicked leads to same transaction page. the transaction amount by default is set to 1 but i want it to change based on the plan selected.

```
 // THERE ARE TWO OTHER SIMILAR PLANS WITH DIFFERENT PRICE
        <h1>Basic</h1>
        <div class="price">
            <h2>₹ 99/-</h2> //the price of the plan
        </div>
        <div class="deals">
            <h4>High Quality</h4>
            <h4>No downloads</h4>
            <h4>ads</h4>
            <h4>No tunes</h4>
            <h4>1 Device</h4>           
        </div>
        <a href="http://localhost/discobeats/php/paytm/TxnTest.php">BUY Now</a>
   </div>
```

This is code for transaction page:

```
//It is a form which contains a table <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td><label>txnAmount*</label></td>
                <td><input title="TXN_AMOUNT" tabindex="10"
                    type="text" name="TXN_AMOUNT"          //HERE DEFAULT VALUE IS 1 BUT I WANT TO CHANGE IT BASED ON PLAN SELECTED
                    value="1">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

[IMAGE OF TRANSACTION PAGE IN BROWSER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x13wj.jpg)
[IMAGE OF SUBSCRIPTION PAGE AS VIEWED IN BROWSER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpBLX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET method and retrieve it in the second page, for example:

```
 <h1>Basic</h1>
        <div class="price">
            <h2>₹ 99/-</h2> //the price of the plan
        </div>
        <div class="deals">
            <h4>High Quality</h4>
            <h4>No downloads</h4>
            <h4>ads</h4>
            <h4>No tunes</h4>
            <h4>1 Device</h4>           
        </div>
        <a href="http://localhost/discobeats/php/paytm/TxnTest.php?product=first">BUY Now</a>
   </div>
```

And this is the second page:

```
<?php
switch($_GET['product']){
case 'first':
$cost = 99;
break;
...
}
?>
 <td>5</td>
                <td><label>txnAmount*</label></td>
                <td><input title="TXN_AMOUNT" tabindex="10"
                    type="text" name="TXN_AMOUNT"          //HERE DEFAULT VALUE IS 1 BUT I WANT TO CHANGE IT BASED ON PLAN SELECTED
                    value="<?php echo $cost;?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much i will try to implement it.